# Diverting the output of a c++ that calls python mangles it

Tags: python, c++, windows

I have a c++ (VS2019) app

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf( "- before\n" );

    FILE* file;
    Py_SetPath( L"c:\\Python37\\Lib" );
    Py_Initialize();
    file = fopen( "abc.py", "r" );
    PyRun_SimpleFile( file, "abc.py" );
    Py_Finalize();

    printf( "- after\n" );

    return;
}
```

that calls a python (3.10) script abc.py

```
print( "hi" );
```

When run (on Win11) from cmd (`main.exe`), the output is:

```
- before
hi
- after
```

However, when diverted into a file (`main.exe > out.txt`, or used in a pipe to tee), I get:

```
hi
- before
- after
```

In my real app, where I interleave python with c++, the python output is printed after the script terminates (again, only when diverting the app's output).

---

Adding

`setbuf( stdout, NULL );`

, like @retired-ninja suggested, resolves the simple example above. However, in my more complicated app, it doesn't. I need to find a new simple example.

---

I only needed to add auto-flush to my python script to resolve the issue:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)
```

Comment: `stdout` is generally buffered. You can flush the buffer with `fflush(stdout)` or possibly change the buffering mode. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf

Comment: I'm not following. What does it have to do with the mangled print order? Are c++ and python stdout different here? How do you suggest to resolve my issue in my minimal example using flush?